# Change OpenVPN client, can I use the same server configurations using scp?

Tags: scp, openvpn, fedora

I want to change my old FC 4 client to new Fedora 19 client, but I need to use all the same files on openvpn and IP address.

Can I use SCP command for copy all this configurations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it should work, but since the version of OpenVPN client on Fedora 4 is pretty old you might encounter some inconsistencies regarding option names and usage.

Yes scp can used to copy openvpn client configs and certificates to the new Fedora 19 client.